# Choose string between two chars that repeat multiple times in a string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a string '"&"abc1"#"1"&""abc2"#"2"&""abc3"#"3"&""abc1"#"4

I just want to extract each int into separate variables. Currently I have
note endtext = "#"
and endnum = "&"

```
WHILE @N < LEN(@TextField)
BEGIN

SET @read1 = (
SELECT SUBSTRING(@TextFieled, 
CHARINDEX(@endtext, @TextFieled) + @N --Increment 2 so skips to next "
, CHARINDEX(@endnum,@TextFieled) - CHARINDEX(@endtext, @TextFieled)) --MANY         CHARS TO GO FOR
)

SELECT @read1

SET @N = @N + CHARINDEX(@read1, @TextFieled) --next strating point
END
```

But it is not returning only numbers. I think the problem lies with the fact that the nums I want to pick are located in repeated strings, so I'm not sure how to alter my loop to skip.

Comment: Please tag your questions appropriately.  The code is clearly SQL Server (or at least T-SQL).  Use the sql-server tag, not mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For readability and debug-ability use variable to store `CHARINDEX`

```
DECLARE 
    @N int = 2, 
    @TextField varchar(100) = '"&"abc1"#"1"&""abc2"#"2"&""abc3"#"3"&""abc1"#"4',
    @read1 varchar(10),
    @endtext varchar(3) = '"#"',
    @endnum varchar(3) = '"&"',
    @Start int,
    @Finish int


WHILE @N < LEN(@TextField)
BEGIN

SET @Start = CHARINDEX(@endtext, @TextField, @N)
SET @Finish =CHARINDEX(@endnum, @TextField, @N)
IF @Finish = 0 SET @Finish = LEN(@TextField) + 1

SET @read1 = (SELECT SUBSTRING(@TextField, @Start + 3, @Finish - @Start - 3))
SELECT @read1 xRead

SET @N = @Finish + 1 --next strating point
END
```

Comment: Perfect, Thank you!